# Assembly language program to display letters in an alphabet in pyramid based on user's input

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I am writing an assembly program to display letters in alphabet in pyramid based on the user's input. Example, if the user input letter a, the output would be:
a
ab
abc
.
.
.
abcdef...z

and if the user enters letter b, this would be the output:

b
bc
bcd
bcde
.
.
.
bcdefg...z

and so on...

below is my code and i'm really having problem about iterations, loops, nested loops, etc. i've been trying but to no avail. i am new to assembly language so my codes really sucks.

```
title print_alphabets

ststack segment para stack 'stack'
        dw 200h
ststack ends

cdata segment para 'data'
        inputMessage db 'Enter a letter to start from: $'
        invalidInput db 10, 13, 'You have entered an invalid character. Please run the program again.$'
        newline db 10, 13, '$'
cdata ends

ccode segment para 'code'
        assume cs: ccode, ss: ststack, ds: cdata

    main:   
        mov ax, cdata
            mov ds, ax

        mov ah, 09h
            lea dx, inputMessage
            int 21h

            mov ah, 01h
            int 21h

        mov bl, al

        mov ch, 26

        mov cl, 26

    testinput:
        cmp bl, 7ah
        jbe loop1

        jmp invalid

    loop1:
        mov ah, 09h
            lea dx, newline
            int 21h 

        mov ah, 02h
            mov dl, bl
            int 21h

        dec ch

        cmp ch, 25
        je loop1

        cmp ch, 24
        jle loop2

        jmp endprog

        loop2:
            inc dl

            mov ah, 02h
                mov dl, dl
                int 21h

            dec cl

            cmp cl, 25
            je loop1
                ;repeat loop2 once
                cmp cl, 24
                je loop2

            cmp cl, 23
            je loop1
                ;repeat loop2 twice
                cmp cl, 22
                je loop2

                cmp cl, 21
                je loop2

            cmp cl, 20
            je loop1
                ;repeat loop2 thrice
                cmp cl, 19
                je loop2

                cmp cl, 18
                je loop2

                cmp cl, 17
                je loop2

            cmp cl, 16
            je loop1
                ;repeat loop2 4 times
                cmp cl, 15
                je loop2

                cmp cl, 14
                je loop2

                cmp cl, 13
                je loop2

                cmp cl, 12
                je loop2

            cmp cl, 11
            je loop1
                ;repeat loop2 5 times
                cmp cl, 10
                je loop2

                cmp cl, 9
                je loop2

                cmp cl, 8
                je loop2

                cmp cl, 7
                je loop2

                cmp cl, 6
                je loop2

            jmp endprog

    invalid:
        mov ah, 09h
        lea dx, invalidInput
        int 21h

        jmp endprog

    endprog:
        mov ah, 4ch
        int 21h
ccode ends
end main
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to program assembler is to write some pseudocode (or other language) and then translate that to assembler.

```
c = input value
for i = c to 'a' + 26
  for k = c to i
    output k
  next k
  output space
next i
```

You only need two increment and jumps.

Comment: Thank you for taking time replying to my question. I think I was able to figure it out. I would like to share my code but I couldn't find it. This was too long ago when I was still pursuing my bachelor degree. :)

Cheers!